# remove 'year' from a date filtered with 'naturalday'

Tags: django, django-templates

I am using the naturalday filter in a template, like

```
{{ reply.createdate| naturalday }}
```

which gives me:

```
yesterday
March 1, 2015
February 20, 2015
```

But that is too long, so I want to remove the year. 
How can I strip the `, 2015`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a format argument to `naturalday`. If you omit the format, it will automatically assume the default date format specified by `DATE_FORMAT`.

So, for your case you can use:

```
{{ reply.createdate | naturalday:"F j" }}
```

See [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/humanize/#naturalday) for details.